# PHP exception not being caught, laravel, lumen

Tags: php, laravel, exception, lumen

When attempting to catch/handle an exception thrown from [PDFParser](https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser), I cannot catch it. I use a simple try catch statement, outlined below.

```
try{
  $pdf  = $parser->parseFile($filepath);
  $text = $pdf->getText();    
} catch( \Exception $e){
  $text = $paper->abstract;
}
```

The exception is thrown as follows.

```
if (empty($data)) {
        throw new \Exception('Object list not found. Possible secured file.');
}
```

> The output is here.
>
> lumen.ERROR: Exception: Object list not found. Possible secured file.
>   in
>
> /Users/pietrosette/Documents/CS_310/AcademicWordCloud-Backend/vendor/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php:98
>   Stack trace:
>
> #0 /Users/pietrosette/Documents/CS_310/AcademicWordCloud-Backend/vendor/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php(74):
>   Smalot\PdfParser\Parser->parseContent('%PDF-1.5\r%\xE2\xE3\xCF\xD3\r...')
>
> #1 /Users/pietrosette/Documents/CS_310/AcademicWordCloud-Backend/app/Http/Controllers/ACMServer.php(198):
>   Smalot\PdfParser\Parser->parseFile('/Users/pietrose...')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your catch:

```
try{
  $pdf  = $parser->parseFile($filepath);
  $text = $pdf->getText();    
} catch( \Execption $e){
  $text = $paper->abstract;
}
```

"Exception" is spelled incorrectly.

Comment: Is it still the same mistake?

Comment: Yes, I ended up changing it to:


        if($pdf === "PDF >= 1.5" ){
            $text = "paper->abstract";
        } else  {
            $text = $pdf->getText();
        }


with a wrapper of
        public function parseFile($filename)
    {
        $content = file_get_contents($filename);
        $return = @$this->parseContent($content);
        if($return === false ){
            return "PDF >= 1.5";
        } else{
            return $return;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a wrapper and returning a different value. This ended up working and was actually quite a bit faster since it is not encapsulated in a try/catch block.

```
    public function parseFile($filename)
    {
        $content = file_get_contents($filename);
        $return = @$this->parseContent($content);
        if($return === false ){
            return "PDF >= 1.5";
        } else{
            return $return;
        }
    }


    public function parseContent($content)
    {
        ...

        if (isset($xref['trailer']['encrypt'])) {
            return false;
        }

        if (empty($data)) {
            return false;
        }
        ....
   }
```

Which lead to modifying my function to the following.

```
    $pdf = $parser->parseFile($filepath);

    if($pdf === "PDF >= 1.5" ){
        $text = $abstract;
    } else  {
        $text = $pdf->getText();
    }
```