# PdfParser issue in PHP

Tags: php, pdfparser

Thank you in advance

I am using the `PdfParser` library to extract text from PDF

My current code for that is as below

```
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdfsource = $parser->parseFile($dest_path);
$pages  = $pdfsource->getPages();
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $final_text.=strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $page->getText()));
}
```

It is working well but for some PDF getting below Exception

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Object list not found. Possible secured file. in /var/www/html/pdfparser-master/vendor/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php:102 Stack trace: #0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176364/php-exception-not-being-caught-laravel-lumen

Comment: Hi
Thanks, can you explain to me the issue bit more if possible?

Comment: You can use try catch to get more information on the exception: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp